# I have a generator that can produce 150 watts, i have a dc motor that takes in 100watts, why is it that my generator wont run the motor?

Tags: power-supply, power, generator

I am trying to simplify this as much as possible as there are tons of variables that people could point out, but i made a small generator which then I rectify to produce DC straight out of the coils, I get 300V, and .5 amps so 150 watts when i spin this generator with a drill. I use a converter to turn the 300v into 24vDC at almost .6 amps, the exact numbers my generator says it needs to run, yet it barely runs without a load and with a load it still lags, why? it looks like its barely running at 20-30%

Comment: How did you measure the 300V and 0.5A? Were they measured at the same time or is one the open-circuit voltage and the other the short-circuit current?

Comment: 24V times 0.6A is 14 W only, not 100W. Also, converting 300 V 0.5 A DC into 24 V DC should be able to produce at least 5 A of current. Can your converter produce this current? If not, you have a very bad converter, and this is the problem.

Comment: Show how you measued 300 V and 0.5 A. Show motor spec.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming "the exact numbers my generator says it needs to run" is a typo and you mean motor.

Your issue is likely the start-up current required by the motor is way larger than the run time current. Motors need lots of oomph to get going, 100W is when up to speed only.